# How to delete a machine type on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

On Google Compute Engine, is there a way to delete a machine type?

Comment: Can you provide some context regarding why you want to do this?

Comment: i need to make a CRUD for the MachinesTypes. in theory, i can create a custom MachinesType, so.. i think is posible delete it, or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really create or delete [machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances#machineType). When you [create a VM with a custom machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type), you just specify the number of cpus and amount of memory you want. This will not result in a new machine type resource (and does not show up when you list all the available machine types).

Comment: I think you're right about deleting it, but I found a property called DeprecationStatus that contains several statuses like "DELETED" and if the machineType has this state then it's impossible to create an instance with that machineType, but I still can not find a way to modify that property , you will know how ??

Answer (score 0):

You can create and delete custom machines the same way as you can create and delete standard machines. In terms of 'types', although you are able to create custom machines in Google Cloud Platform they aren't a savable resource in the sense that you can save/delete it as a 'type'. 
However, you can save/create/delete custom machines as images or alternatively instance templates.

If you save a custom instance as an image, it is essentially a custom instance before it's inception, so by deleting the custom image, you are essentially deleting a machine type if you consider custom images 'types' of machines that have yet to be booted. Deleting a custom image can be achieved by running:

```
gcloud compute images delete [IMAGE]
```

Likewise, instance templates can be customised to generate custom instances. The template defines a machine specification which you can use to boot new machines. In a similar way to the images example, depending on how you define the deleting of machine types, you could consider deleting a custom template as deleting a custom Compute Engine machine type. Deleting an instance template can be achieved by running the following command:

```
gcloud compute instance-templates delete [INSTANCE TEMPLATE]
```

For more information on creating and deleting custom images please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images). 
For more information on creating instance templates please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates).